# Batch convert local HTML webpages to plain text

Tags: html, eww, batch-mode

Here is my zsh code

```sh
function eweb() {
    emacsclient -t --eval "(eww-open-file \"$1\")" "(save-buffer \"$2\")"
}
```

There are two parameters, the first is the local webpage filename, for example, `./1.html`. The second parameter is the filename I want to save the text to. For example, `1.org`.
This code can open the webage successfully, **but it cannot pass the second parameter to `save-buffer`**.

What's more, it cannot finish the procedure silently, which means it **cannot be used to batch convert HTML to text**.

How can I solve these two problems?

Comment: Put everything inside a (progn ...) form, then escape intermediate quotation marks.

Comment: Thank you @InHarmsWay .I did what you say, `eweb () {
        emacsclient -t --eval (progn \"(eww-open-file \"$1\")\" \"(save-buffer \"$2\")\")
}
`, but it shows error.

Comment: What is the error?  And you shouldn’t escape the opening and closing quotation marks. I’ll add an answer

Comment: Untested, but try this:  emacsclient -t —eval \”(progn (eww-open-file \\\”$1\\\”)(save-buffer \\\”$2\\\”))\”

Comment: That quoting was for .gitconfig. In a shell script you can also experiment with —eval “(progn (eww-open-file \”$1\”)(save-buffer \”$2\”))”

Comment: Are you *particularly* wanting to use Emacs for this?  I wouldn't expect it to be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

To pass multiple expressions to `emacsclient` (and `emacs` as well), you have two options.

The first option is grouping them into one expression with `progn`:

```
function eweb() { 
    emacsclient -e "(progn (eww-open-file \"$1\") (write-region nil nil \"$2\"))"
}
```

The second option is using multiple `-e/--eval`:

```
function eweb() {
    emacsclient -e "(eww-open-file \"$1\")" -e "(write-region nil nil \"$2\")"
}
```

By default, `emacsclient` prints the value of each expression, for example,

```
$ emacsclient -e 1 -e 2 -e 3
1
2
3
$
```

Since Emacs 26.1, you can the `-u/--suppress-output` option to disable the behaviour

> -u, --suppress-output   Don't display return values from the server

With the option, `emacsclient` will print nothing.

```
$ emacsclient -u -e 1 -e 2 -e 3
$
```

Comment: Emacsclient can accept an arbitrary number of s-expressions to evaluate after the `--eval` option. It is Emacs which only accepts a single expression per `--eval` option.

Comment: @Basil Oh, you're right. I didn't know that. I think the real issue is that OP (@yuxuan) misused `save-buffer`.

Comment: Yes, when they were most likely after `write-file`/`write-region`.